# Selecting Aggregate from a Child Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE accounts (
  account_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE payments (
  payment_id INT NOT NULL,
  account_id INT NOT NULL,
  amount DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
  extra_charge TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts (account_id)
);
```

Payments belong to accounts and accounts belong to users.

I'd like to select all rows in `accounts` belonging to a particular user, along with the sum of the `amount` column from the child table `payments`, but only for payments where the `extra_charge` column is 0.

I started off using a sub-query:

```
SELECT
  a.account_id,
  COALESCE(t.total_amount, 0) total_amount
FROM
  accounts a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    p.account_id,
    SUM(p.amount) total_amount
  FROM
    payments p
  WHERE
    p.extra_charge = 0
  GROUP BY
    p.account_id
) p USING (account_id)
WHERE
  a.user_id = ?;
```

But this runs slowly because summing the entire `payments` table is a lot of needless work. I can avoid needlessly summing the entire `payments` table by doing this:

```
SELECT
  a.account_id,
  COALESCE(t.total_amount, 0) total_amount
FROM
  accounts a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    p.account_id,
    SUM(p.amount) total_amount
  FROM
    payments p
  LEFT JOIN
    accounts a USING (account_id)
  WHERE
    a.user_id = ?
      AND
    p.extra_charge = 0
  GROUP BY
    p.account_id
) p USING (account_id)
WHERE
  a.user_id = ?;
```

But supplying `user_id` twice seemed messy.

I also tried write it without a sub-query using only joins:

```
SELECT
  a.account_id
  SUM(p.amount) total_amount
FROM
  accounts a
LEFT JOIN
  payments p USING (account_id)
WHERE
  a.user_id = ?
    AND
  p.extra_charge = 0
GROUP BY
 a.account_id;
```

But then my result was missing any accounts that didn't have payments (or didn't have any payments with `extra_charge` = 0).

Can anyone suggest a better way to write this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

Instead of

```
SELECT
  a.account_id,
  SUM(p.amount) total_amount
FROM
  accounts a
LEFT JOIN
  payments p USING (account_id)
WHERE
  a.user_id = ?
   AND
 p.extra_charge = 0
GROUP BY
  a.account_id;
```

I used

```
SELECT
  a.account_id,
  COALESCE(SUM(p.amount), 0) total_amount
FROM
  accounts a
LEFT JOIN
  payments p ON p.account_id = a.account_id AND p.extra_charge = 0
WHERE
  a.user_id = ?
GROUP BY
  a.account_id;
```

I widened the WHERE clause but restricted the JOIN. Now I get accounts with no valid payments too.

Answer (score 0):

use join and where clause for filter

```
select u.user_id ,p.account_id ,sum(p.amount) as totalAmount
from payments p inner join accounts a
on a.account_id=p.account_id 
inner join users u on a.user_id=u.user_id
where p.extra_charge =0
group by u.user_id ,p.account_id
```

Comment: Like my third example, this query doesn't return any accounts with no payments (or no payments where `extra_charge` = 0)

Comment: @Dave yes if you restrict by using filter then it will not return any account id and join is the best way

Comment: @Dave does it helps ?

Comment: I was able to do it by not making the WHERE clause so restrictive and narrowing down my JOIN clause. I had to make it a LEFT JOIN with accounts as the primary table. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51791734/3438226 Thanks though!